# Supporting older browsers (lte IE 10)?

Tags: mapbox-gl-js

As far as I can see, Mapbox GL JS is not supported by IE 10 and below. Correct?

I want to implement GL-JS for my site, but need to support these incompatible browsers, and am hoping to find an elegant solution, probably just showing them the mapbox tile layer I'm currently using.

I thought IE conditional comments would do it, but they only work up to IE9, leaving a gap where a lot of my users are.

I know I can use `if (!mapboxgl.supported())` within the javascript function block, but I also need to conditionally load the javascript and css files. No point loading them both - would probably cause conflicts, and it's just plain dodgy.

So… suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

Mapbox GL JS renders maps using WebGL which is only supported in IE11+

If compatibility is important, you have two options:

1. use Mapbox.js (raster tiles) in all cases
2. use Mapbox GL JS in supported browsers, use Mapbox.js in unsupported browsers

You can check for support without loading unnecessary Javascript or CSS files by using the [`mapbox-gl-supported`](https://github.com/mapbox/mapbox-gl-supported) module and loading additional JS and CSS files dynamically

```
var scriptElement = document.createElement('script');
scriptElement.setAttribute('src', 'https://api.mapbox.com/mapbox-gl-js/v0.20.1/mapbox-gl.js');
document.body.appendChild(scriptElement);
```

Comment: Lucas, thanks for this, I've been on holiday, so only just got back to try it out. It looks to be exactly what I want, but, I seem to be missing something and cannot make it work. :-(

Without even resorting to the mapbox-gl-supported module, I attempted to simply load the js using this method and got nothing.

Clearly, I'm not a js expert. This is all I got: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1039367/browser.html

Comment: OK, so I have managed to dynamically load items, but I run into problems with the order in which they load. The script in the body of the page, asks for the map before the remote javascript has loaded - BOOM!! A working example would be delightful, though I realise this may be a stretch!

Comment: Yes, the check-for-suppot example is fine in a 'hello world' fashion, but I need to do better than an alert. So, I have tried to use the technique to present the old style of map, but this is where it breaks down. This was as far as I got: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1039367/mapboxgljs/support-dev.html - it seems to be dynamically loading the correct files, but not in time for the map to be built, so the whole thing falls over.

Comment: I've been trying to move elements around in the vain hope of getting things to load in time, but this is the best I've got so far: https://dl.dropboxusercontent.com/u/1039367/mapboxgljs/support-dev.02.html which, bizarrely, loads only in IE Edge, still fails in all other browsers.